# SQL - If value exists in other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

```
Table A:           Value 1:           Value 2:
id (int)           1                  2
from (varchar)     josh               robert

Table B:           Value 1:           Value 2:
id (int)           1                  2
name (varchar)     josh               robert
surname (varchar)  apple              orange
```

And there is a keyword "apple". How to choose `id` from table A if some value from table B contains `surname` with keyword "apple". In this case result should be `1` (from table A) because `josh` has keyword `apple`.

That's what I did:

```
mysql_query("SELECT id FROM A WHERE from IN (SELECT name FROM B WHERE surname LIKE '%apple%')");`
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`from` is a reserved keyword. Escape it:

```
select id
from A
where `from` in (
        select name
        from B
        where surname like '%apple%'
        )
```

You can also use join:

```
select a.id
from a
join b on a.`from` = b.name
where b.surname like '%apple%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JOIN`, e.g.:

```
SELECT ta.id
FROM tableA ta JOIN tableB tb ON ta.`from` = b.name
WHERE tb.surname = 'apple';
```